# Datatype conversion issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can to fetch data from table but getting below error.

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting
>   the varchar value '0 0' to data type int.

Below is the code which i am using

[image]

Comment: You've got a varchar. It contains 3 characters - two `0`s separated by a space. There's not a sensible way to convert that to an `int`. That's what the error is telling you, and that's all we can tell you - you need to work out things like which column contains that data, whether that data is valid, why you're trying to convert it to an `int` and, if that's a sensible conversion, what actual value you would expect it to convert to (plus, if necessary, specify other possible inputs and expected outputs). We can't do those things for you.

Comment: there is no such type of data present in base tables. Also when i remove the case statement of group by clause, same is working properly

Comment: Denying the data exists is not a healthy strategy for fixing the problem. As a hint, the data is probably in one of the following columns - currentbalance, highcredit_sanctionedamount, mob, amountoverdue or customerid - those are the ones being used in positions where a conversion to `int` are obvious in your query.

Comment: @user3304978 you need to provide the table data. it seems like a data issue

Answer (score 0):

'0 0' is not an integer. That is why the error is occurring. The space between two zeros is making it an invalid integer.

Comment: on what line exactly is the error is occurring. add your code as text.

Comment: the case statement of group by clause because when i remove that part same is working properly

Comment: check values in column AmountOverdue,HighCredit_Sanctionedamount and currentbalance. try casting all values in these columns to int

Answer (score 0):

fetch into varchar variable. Then check value and reassign to int variable.
For example
declare @tmpVal varchar,
        @intVal int
...
fetch into @tmpVal
if(@tmpVal = '0 0')
    SET @intVal = 0
else
    SET @intVal = CAST(@tmpVal as int)